# I need to use the same JS code but it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a code block that only appears after a checkbox is checked, but this block is inside a foreach, it will be repeated more than once. the first one works when I click the checkbox, the second repetition no longer works.
how can I solve?

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-3" id="2">Adicionar 2ª cor  <input type="checkbox" id="isChecked_3"/></div>
                            <div id="cor4" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-3">
                                    <label for="sel5"><h6>Selecionar Cor 2:<h6></label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="sel5" name="{{ $proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_2'}}">
                                            <option value="0">Selecionar Cor</option>
                                                @foreach ($colors as $color)
                                                    <option value="{{ $color->id_color }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#isChecked_3').change(function(){
                    if($(this).prop('checked')){
                        $('#cor4').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#cor4').hide();
                    }
                    
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: I think it's because `$(document).ready` only fires once when the document is ready.

Comment: @noob, You're right in that `$document.ready()` only fires once, but it's setting up a `change` event handler that should fire every time there's a change on the selected element.

Comment: Hi can you show for loop ? and proper html

Answer (score 0):

An `id` must be unique on the page. You're using `id="cor4"` for all the affected `<DIV>` elements, so you're lucky to have anything working. You could change the `id` for a class and work on that, but you still have the problem of the `id` applied to your `<select>` element.

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-3" id="2">Adicionar 2ª cor  <input type="checkbox" id="isChecked_3"/></div>

                            <!-- Change id to class here -->
                            <div class="cor4" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-3">
                                    <label for="sel5"><h6>Selecionar Cor 2:<h6></label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="sel5" name="{{ $proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_2'}}">
                                            <option value="0">Selecionar Cor</option>
                                                @foreach ($colors as $color)
                                                    <option value="{{ $color->id_color }}">{{ $color->name }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#isChecked_3').change(function(){
                    if($(this).prop('checked')){

                        // Change id selector to class selector here...
                        $('.cor4').show();
                    } else {

                        // ...and here
                        $('.cor4').hide();
                    }
                    
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: no, id 4 is unique, there is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, when it runs inside a foreach the second one stops working

Comment: Ok - the `id` might be unique, but the code you've posted is still only selecting one `id`. If you're about to tell me that you've created lots of different event handlers then you're tackling this the wrong way. You need to post more code.